# Handling dynamic table using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, list, selenium, set

I am trying to extract all the rows from a dynamic scroll-able table where it only shows about 30 rows at a time. My idea was to run it though a while loop till final row's "data-index" attribute matches and scroll using a JavascriptExecutor class but keep on getting StaleElementReferenceException.

```
    Set<WebElement> songsTr = new HashSet<WebElement>();
    List<WebElement> dynamicSongTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@data-count='273']/tr"));

    while (!dynamicSongTable.get(dynamicSongTable.size()-2).getAttribute("data-index").equalsIgnoreCase("272")) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dynamicSongTable.size()-1; i++) {
            songsTr.add(dynamicSongTable.get(i));
        }
        WebElement element = dynamicSongTable.get(dynamicSongTable.size()-1);
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    }

    System.out.println(songsTr.size());
```

[Picture of the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhbmZ.jpg)

Comment: Instead of storing a set of web elements, could you store a set of some unique identifier (like an id tag) that can later be referred to?

Comment: Hi ~  @Azfar you may paste your full stacktrace of your error log.

Answer (score 1):

`StaleElementReferenceException` comes when the element you are operating on is no longer present in the dom or has become stale. So in order to correct it, you need to again fetch the element before operating on it.

In your case, it would be like:

```
Set<WebElement> songsTr = new HashSet<WebElement>();
List<WebElement> dynamicSongTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@data-count='273']/tr"));

while (!dynamicSongTable.get(dynamicSongTable.size()-2).getAttribute("data-index").equalsIgnoreCase("272")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicSongTable.size()-1; i++) {
        songsTr.add(dynamicSongTable.get(i));
    }
    WebElement element = dynamicSongTable.get(dynamicSongTable.size()-1);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    dynamicSongTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@data-count='273']/tr"));
}

System.out.println(songsTr.size());
```